# Infer AWS Glue Data Catalog Schema from XSD rather than using a craw

Tags: xsd, aws-glue

Is it possible to use XSD files to infer a schema for an AWS Glue Data Catalog?

Using a crawler to guess the schema of XML Files can be quite error-prone. Is it possible to directly use XSD Files in Glue to create a table definition in the data catalog?

Answer (score 1):

Glue Crawlers don't support creation of Data Catalog tables based on schema definitions, instead they are designed to crawl the data and infer a schema as best they can.

Unfortunately your next option might be to consider using the Data Catalog API to create the schema based on the XSD files. The ease (or not) of this approach will depend on the complexity of the data types defined in your XML files.

This approach can be tested with relative ease by allowing the crawler to infer results from test data, and the manually adjusting any incorrect data types.

An alternative approach when you have a schema definition available can be to use the Spark APIs directly to create a Spark Schema type based on your schema definition, and then provide it to the DataFrameReader (provided this supports XML) so that Spark can read your source XML with the schema you have provided to apply the appropriate data types. See [DataFrameReader.schema(...)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#schema-java.lang.String-) for details.